# Iam kind of new into dictionaries, so can you explain how can i write a function like the below one

Tags: python

i want to write a function that takes a list and returns a dictionary containing lists of indices for every item that appears in the list
for example:

```
input: indices(['a','a','b','b'])
output: {'a':[0,1],'b':[2,3]}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def indices(aList):
    aDict = {}

    for i in range(0, len(aList)):
        letter = aList[i]
        if letter in aDict:
            aDict[letter] += [i]
        else:
            aDict[letter] =  [i]

    return aDict


print( indices(['a','a','b','b']) )         # For testing only
```

Output:

> {'b': [2, 3], 'a': [0, 1]}

Explanation:

1. For every position in the original list retrieve the content.
2. Ask if it exists (as a key) in the dictionary.

   a) if yes, add the current position to the list of values of that key,

   b) if not, create the entry with the list of this (meanwhile only 1) position.

Comment: Does your output match the example output from the question?

Comment: Yeah but its missing the order of the value

Comment: for example, b is third in order, to print 2

Comment: Well, this solution only counts the number of elements. Look at my attempt for a solution that matches your output.

Comment: @JohanL - Thank for your notice, I corrected (rewrote) my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution to get what you ask for:

```
mylist = ['a','a','b','b']
mydict = {}
for index, element in enumerate(mylist):
    mydict.setdefault(element, []).append(index)
```

It is rather straightforward. The `for` loop is enumerating and accessing the elements of the original list one by one. If the element is not found in `mydict` already, a default empty list is created. Then, whether newly created or not, the index of the new element is added to the previous list of indices.

*) Edited per suggestion in comments.

Comment: Eh, why is my attempt down voted? Sure, there may be other solutions but at least this one produces what OP was asking for.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably someone is trying to discourage people form answering bad questions.

Comment: OK, I could agree with that, but this question isn't much worse than many others. And, it would still be nice with a comment in that case.

Comment: I am only speculating, and it's based on the fact that it seems everything was downvoted.

Comment: Well, the other 'answer' is wrong. (I am not the one to down vote it, though.)

Comment: As an aside, consider the method `mydict.setdefault(element, []).append(index)` That is all you need in your loop body, no need for `partial`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144284/discussion-between-johanl-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Comment: FWIW, code-only answers are generally frowned upon on Stack Overflow

Comment: @JohanL Thank you, i really appreciate your effort trying to help me :)